# Why lunar day lasts exactly one month?

Tags: orbital-motion, moon

Therefore we don't see dark side of the moon. Is the core of the Moon closer to the Earth than the center of the moon? Or what is the reason?

[image: Lunar motion]

Comment: The effect is called tidal locking. [See the WP page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_locking) for more info.

Comment: *"Therefore we don't see dark side of the moon."* `s/dark/other/g;` FTFY. The moon gets sunlight all the way 'round. Think about it.

Answer (score -2):

Earth rotation is slowing dowm through ebb and flow and the resulting friction. It will have found it's equilibrium as soon the day on earth will be one month (and the tides will have ended). The moon has finished this earlier, since it's moment of inertia is much lower

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: As far as I understand this I explained what's the principle behind tidal locking. Didn't know this term though uintil your comment. Or am I wrong?